# No embeddedresource found for xxx.App on android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I originally ran this project on a Windows partition but decided to move it to my mac. (Maybe it is part of the problem)

I realize that every time I try to compile the project to an android device, I get the following exception in `App.xaml.g.cs`:

> **Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException has been thrown**
>
> No embeddedresource found for xx.App

I can, however, bypass this exception by cleaning and rebuilding the project every time I have made changes to my code.

I've too tried to delete my obj and bin folders in all solutions, but the problem persists.

Comment: could you show us your csproj ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to access an asset which is missing from the project Folder. Kindly check the code which resource is missing usually some .db3 file or some font or some image.

For Android:
The resource is in Assets Folder and the Build Action is Android Asset

For iOS:
The resource is in Resoures folder and the BuildAction is BundleResource.